# What to do when travelling between countries?

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm curious about what's gonna happen if I go from one country to another (both with Pokemon Go available) does it consider it as teleporting or not?

Comment: As far as I know the game itself does not differentiate between countries, just continents. You should at most expect a soft-ban if you travel too large of a distance in too little time. You should also keep in mind that your data bundle might not be valid in the other country, making running Pokemon GO very expensive.

Answer (score 3):

**Nothing happens**. As long as you are travelling distances with real-life vehicles, such as cars, trains or airplanes, nothing is the matter. If you are going by teleportation, then you can encounter a soft-ban.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think even the fastest (supersonic) airplanes would result in a softban as it's not fast enough, not to mention you wouldn't have internet access while in transit so the effective speed would be even less.

If the app is closed the distance traveled since your last known position will be known by the game as well as the time that this took. So if you are worried about the fact that you are thousands of kilometers since you last logged in, there is no need to be worried.